# Sending JSON using the django test client

Tags: django, json, unit-testing

I'm working on a django a project that will serve as the endpoint for a webhook. The webhook will POST some JSON data to my endpoint, which will then parse that data. I'm trying to write unit tests for it, but I'm not sure if I'm sending the JSON properly.

I keep getting "TypeError: string indices must be integers" in pipeline_endpoint

Here's the code:

```
# tests.py
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client
import simplejson

class TestPipeline(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        """initialize the Django test client"""
        self.c = Client()

    def test_200(self):
        json_string = u'{"1": {"guid": "8a40135230f21bdb0130f21c255c0007", "portalId": 999, "email": "fake@email"}}'
        json_data = simplejson.loads(json_string)
        self.response = self.c.post('/pipeline-endpoint', json_data, content_type="application/json")
        self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code, "200")
```

and

```
# views.py
from pipeline.prospect import Prospect
import simplejson

def pipeline_endpoint(request):

    #get the data from the json object that came in
    prospects_json = simplejson.loads(request.raw_post_data)
    for p in prospects_json:
        prospect = {
            'email'          : p['email'],
            'hs_id'          : p['guid'],
            'portal'         : p['portalId'],
        }
```

Edit: whole traceback.

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_200 (pipeline.tests.TestPipeline)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\......\pipeline\tests.py", line 31, in test_200
    self.response = self.c.post('/pipeline-endpoint', json_string, content_type="application/json")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 455, in post
    response = super(Client, self).post(path, data=data, content_type=content_type, **extra)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 256, in post
    return self.request(**r)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "F:\......\pipeline\views.py", line 18, in pipeline_endpoint
    'email'          : p['email'],
TypeError: string indices must be integers

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.095s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Comment: Is it... because you should be using `json.dumps` (with a python object) rather than `json.loads` (with a string), and hence you are sending through a python object with your client request, rather than a python object serialised as a json object?

Answer (score 99):

@mrmagooey is right

```python
def test_your_test(self):
    python_dict = {
        "1": {
            "guid": "8a40135230f21bdb0130f21c255c0007",
            "portalId": 999,
            "email": "fake@email"
        }
    }
    response = self.client.post('/pipeline-endpoint/',
                                json.dumps(python_dict),
                                content_type="application/json")
```

use `json.dumps` instead of `json.loads`

Answer (score 24):

`rest_framework`'s [`APIClient`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#apiclient) (which is the the default `client_class` in [`APITestCase`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/test.py#L352)) takes care of dumping `dict` to `JSON` and it sets proper content type by passing `format='json'`.

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase


class MyTestCase(APITestCase):
    url = '/url'

    def post(self, payload, url=None):
        """
        Helper to send an HTTP post.

        @param (dict) payload: request body

        @returns: response
        """
        if url is None:
            url = self.url

        return self.client.post(url, payload, format='json')

    def test_my_function(self):
        payload = {
            'key': 'value'
        }
        response = self.post(payload)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: When importing the APIClient here, how does it affect anything, it doesn't seem to be used?

Comment: @ocodo it doesn't, just wanted to indicated where it's defined.

Comment: Maybe don't, people's pylint etc will complain.

Comment: @ocodo unused import removed; pylint & friends is a good point, thx.

Answer (score 23):

Try:

```
 self.client.generic('POST', '/url', json.dumps({'json': 'object'})
```

Comment: Works well also with 'GET'! Thank you!

Comment: Note that `client.generic()` is undocumented and called by `client.post()` for this case (or `client.get()`, `client.put()`, etc, for other request methods)

Comment: This answer saved me twice. Once in 2019, and another one in 2014.

Comment: how to write this in a parent class to override this for child classes so that this json conversion is written only once?

Answer (score 15):

You can always use the [HttpRequest.body](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body) which loads the raw request data. This way you can handle your own data processing.

```
c = Client()
json_str= json.dumps({"data": {"id": 1}})
c.post('/ajax/handler/', data= json_str, content_type='application/json',
                                         HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest')


def index(request):
    ....
    print json.loads(request.body)
```

Answer (score 10):

Since Django 3.0 you can just add `content_type='application/json'` and pass your data as Python dictionary.

From Django documentation (section [Making requests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.post)):

> If you provide content_type as application/json, the data is
> serialized using json.dumps() if it’s a dict, list, or tuple.
> Serialization is performed with DjangoJSONEncoder by default, and can
> be overridden by providing a json_encoder argument to Client. This
> serialization also happens for put(), patch(), and delete() requests.

```
response = client.post(
    f'/customer/{customer.id}/edit',
    {'email': new_email},
    content_type='application/json'
)
```

Comment: Please provide a link to the documentation you quoted.

Comment: @ניר done! ;)  _(I edited the answer and added the link)_

Answer (score 2):

You can user `iteritems` on dictionaries to loop

```
for index, p in prospects_json.iteritems():
  prospect={
    'email': p['email'],
  }
```

or alternatively

```
for index in prospect_json:
  prospect={
    'email': prospect_json[ index ]['email']
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the iteritems() reminder but I'm still having a JSONDecodeError. Anything look weird with the JSON.

Comment: No, in fact it worked fine in the shell. Can you update your traceback?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Guillaume Vincent's answer, from Django 2.1 we no longer need to use json.dumps for passing the data.

> Changed in Django 2.1:
>   The JSON serialization described above was added. In older versions, you can call json.dumps() on data before passing it to post() to achieve the same thing.