# Is there any way to post list of dictionary in django test client?

Tags: django, python-2.7

As Django Test Client accepts only data={} as an input I am not able to pass a list of dict i.e data=[{},{},{}] to it. Any solution for this?

Comment: How are you expecting that to be posted to the view?

Answer (score 19):

This worked:

```py
response = client.post(url, json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Thanks! This still works in Python 3.9 and Django 4 :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the values as a list in the dict:

```
data={"key": [{"key":"value"}, {"key":"value"}]}
```

Alternatively you can use a MultiValueDict as the value.

You can pass as a list also

```
import requests
data = [{"key":"value"}, {"key":"value"}]
a = requests.post('http://url', data)
```

Comment: I have actually used django rest bulk which accepts list of dict to post multiple objetcs. So I want to post list as an argument to post method. is it possible?

Comment: @jd16 yes it is possible to send a list in url.

Comment: Sorry to provide details piece by piece. Actually, I am writing test cases of django whcih used Client class of tests of django package. So in test cases i am not able to pass the list.

Comment: "list" has no method .items(). So it expects dict in post method. So is there any other client to which I can pass the List of objects ?

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions has helped me, client was always having problems with dumping this list of dicts but I recommend the solution proposed here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39155038/16062106

In your case it will be something like:

```
response = client.generic("GET", URL, data=json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json",)
```